# What are the step by step instructions to do a multi-signature spending account with 2 of 5 people?

Tags: multisignature

I'd like to setup an account that requires the approval of 2 of 5 people in order to spend from my ether account. How can this be done step by step?

Comment: You need a smart contract, to write code you have to pay, or we can debug your code, if you make some effort. No meal is free.

Comment: so its not inherent in the ethereum system like how bitcoin has it built?